# what is the geometry meaning of 2D cross product?

Tags: geometry, 2d, line

I have two 2D vectors, like [x1,y1] and [x2,y2]

Some guys define 2d Cross as x1*y2 - y1 * x2

I am wondering what's the meaning of this? Any practical application?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what your question is about and how is it related to programming? Isn't this a pure geometry question?

Comment: you can find the area of the polygon if you have its vertices coordinates as a list of xi, yi.

Comment: Those some guys, aren't they silly? :)

Comment: Have you read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: Read, nothing related to 2D cross products

Comment: @Lawrence, I suppose he should have asked if there was a practical application to programming, which there is.

Answer (score 8):

"2D cross products" are more properly called 2d [wedge products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_product).  Wedge products generalize to other dimensions, but cross products are always 3d wedge products.  The usual operator symbol for a wedge product is `^`.

You can use 2d wedge products to determine if one vector is to the left or the right of another one.  If vector A is to the right of vector B, then `A ^ B > 0`, if A is to the left `A ^ B < 0`.  If they are parallel or either of them is 0, then `A ^ B = 0`.

```
        | Ax Ay |
A ^ B = | Bx By | = Ax By - Ay Bx
```

In vector graphics, 2d wedge products can be used to analyze the intersection of 2 parametrized curves, e.g. for removing portions of one curve that lies to the right of another.  If you have a region defined by a set of bounding curves oriented counterclockwise around the interior of the region, you can then clip a set of curves to the boundary by trimming off the pieces that are to the right of their intersection with a boundary curve.

Comment: I tried for `A = (1,1)` and `B = (2,2)` and got `A^B = 1*2 + 1*2 = 4` - I expected `0` because I thought they would be considered parallel... I am confused... snif, snif...

Comment: @Ely, It should be 1*2 - 1*2, which is 0 as expected.

Comment: That's what I expect to. But the formula used a + instead of a -.

Answer (score 1):

Codie's answer is a good one. I will also note that the "2D cross product" is also commonly referred to as the "perpendicular dot product" or "perp dot product": the dot product of the CCW perpendicular of A with the (original) B. By "CCW perpendicular", I mean the vector 90 degrees counterclockwise; the CCW perpendicular of (x, y) is (-y, x).

Comment: Cool, never heard that term before.

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey There's a fun article in Graphics Gems IV, entitled "The Pleasures of Perp Dot Products".